# Android scroll bar in phonegap application?

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have a problem in android phonegap mobile website application, I applied scroll bar in my application, it is working good in PC but when i test in android device(mobile phone) scroll bar not enable.

Answer (score 1):

personally I don't like iscroll.. had many problems using it so I discovered another solution... you can try this:

1.) set your DIV overflow to auto (or scroll) and set its height.. e.g.

```
     <div id="wrapper" style="overflow:auto; height: 200px">...content...</div>
```

(I usually calculate height with javascript based on user's screen size.. I never set just a fixed height for all devices, this is just for the purpose of this "demo")

2.) add this javascript:

```
      <script>
function isTouchDevice(){
    try{
        document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}

function touchScroll(id){
    if(isTouchDevice()){ //if touch events exist...
        var el=document.getElementById(id);
        var scrollStartPos=0;

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) {
            scrollStartPos=this.scrollTop+event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);

        document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
            this.scrollTop=scrollStartPos-event.touches[0].pageY;
            event.preventDefault();
        },false);
}
} 
</script>
```

3.) call it on page load.. if you use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   touchScroll("wrapper");
});
```

4.) if you want your scrollbars to be visible, just define following CSS rules:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I didn't wanna use any 3rd party library just to show up the scrollbar in my Phonegap Android app. Thanks @Asteriskiiii, I just used 4th step (CSS part only) in my code and the damn scrollbar is shown now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this PhoneGap link

http://phonegap.pbworks.com/w/page/22863184/Hide%20the%20scrollbar%20in%20Android

this works in Android ,PhoneGap Applications for vertical and Horizontal Scroll

Answer (score 0):

Code look Like this

public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

     // Display vertical scrollbar and hide horizontal scrollBar
     super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
     super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // set scrollbar style
    super.appView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
}
```

}